# Why does taking the Discrete Fourier Transform of a histogram make sense?

Tags: fourier-transform

I think I have a serious misunderstanding of the Fast Fourier Transform. Currently, I'm using ROOT to try to analyze some data, and the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) function applies only to histograms.

Why does this make sense? How can one get an accurate transform knowing only the values which were measured and not exactly *when* they were measured?

(The following is clarification as per Glen_b's comment:

(iii) - I have some data of voltage/time that I'd like to take the Fourier Transform of, which I thought would be a discrete Fourier transform, since the data is (obviously) discrete. I was under the impression that the Fast Fourier Transform is just a method of taking a discrete Fourier Transform, and the discrete Fourier Transform is directly analogous to the continuous one.

(ii) & (i) - That being said, I only have limited experience with the continuous transform (from class). I now have some voltage/time data (the type of data you'd see on an oscilloscope) that I'm trying to transform to isolate some noise frequencies. ROOT, the platform through which I am performing the transformation, only has a Fast Fourier Transform method for histograms. Histograms are just counts of numbers, independent of the time. I'm confused as to how one can take the Fourier Transform of counts of numbers and get anything useful from it without knowing the time at which they occurred.)

Comment: (i) Can you give some context? You start by discussing [histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) - which have no time component, then suddenly you're talking about *when* something was measured. It seems like context might help us understand what you're asking about. (ii) What do you mean by 'an accurate transform'? You can apply an FFT to any sequence of values. They don't have to be values over time. The FFT has many different uses. (iii) Why does your title discuss the DFT while your body mentions only the FFT? Why the inconsistency in terms?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the comment; I've edited the main post to make things a bit more clear. Sorry about the vagueness. I'm just pretty confused.

Comment: Histograms are obviously discrete but time can be also. Is time also discrete? Are the histograms changing at each time step?

Comment: @Glen_b The DFT and FFT are used interchangeably but there is a subtle difference. The key difference is that the implementation of a FFT is special algorithm that computes the DFT faster than previous implementations.

Comment: Does ROOT (which I have never heard of) require a set of counts and return the FFT? Or can it work with any sequence of values? e.g. say (3.40, 5.71, 9.22, 8.45,...) instead of (3,6,9,8,...) -- FFT ought to work on either

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher I was trying to suggest to the OP that since the original body text spoke only about FFT that the title should say FFT.

Comment: @Glen_b That's a good point.

Comment: I was too obscure. I should have been more direct.

Comment: Possibly when you say it 'applies only to histograms' do you mean that the output are histograms?

Comment: @Glen_b ROOT can work on any sequence of values, but my confusion comes from the thought that the actual order of the values should matter. That is, since this FFT is being performed on a histogram, (3, 3, 3, 9, 1) would have the same DFT as (3, 9, 1, 3, 3). Root is - "An object oriented framework for large scale data analysis. ROOT is a C++ replacement of the popular PAW program developed at CERN." It's true that I only speak about the FFT, but my question is about DFTs in general (that is, I would still have the question if one took the DFT of a histogram *not* using an FFT algorithm.)

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher The outputs are, too, histograms, but the FFT method itself is also only present for histograms.

Comment: The values in a histogram are ordered. You can't change the order without changing the histogram. If the indices are not ordered, it's not a histogram but something else.  (For the multivariate cases, they're ordered in each variable but this seems to be a univariate case, so that's a non-issue anyway)

Comment: @Glen_b Huh... Oh. Am... I misunderstanding what a histogram is? I thought, if one has data, say, (3, 3, 3, 1, 2) - and puts this data into a histogram with bins of size 1 from 0 to 3, that the histogram would say (0 1 1 3) regardless of the order of the data (the first bin being the number of data labelled '0', the second being the number of '1', the 3rd '2' data points, and the 4th '0'). Is... this wrong? -- That is, I thought a histogram was a count of how many points of data fit into a bin, regardless of the order in which said histogram was filled.

Comment: A histogram would illustrate counts for discrete values. One histogram that would take (3 3 3 1 2) and make three bars. One bar for 1 would be one high because there is only one 1, as with 2, but three would be three high. The other meaning of what you are saying is that you have a histogram counting something unknown to us on CV but known to you, and it is counting 3 things, 3 other things then 1 then 2.

Comment: I think you're confusing two different things. If I take a set of numbers and make a histogram from them, then yes, that loses the ordering in the original values. However, the histogram *itself* is a sequence of values (counts per bin). Once you have a histogram, the order of the bin counts *matters* - if you take the FFT of histogram counts or proportions (which FFT can be meaningful if the bins are constant width), then it certainly matters that you supply the bin counts in order. The FFT of the bin counts is not really related to the FFT of the values from which the histogram was made.

Comment: Right you are counting. And to correct your comment 4th is '3'.

Comment: You can use FFT, for example, to perform convolution on  probability functions or discretized densities. (e.g. I have used it when trying to work out the p.f. of a convolution of a number of negative binomial distributions with both parameters different, apart from the extreme upper tail (the tiny  probability in which could be calculated by the shortfall from 1 of the probabilities that were computed). This gave me all the high quantiles I needed.

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher Oh, thanks. I've edited it to appropriately reflect the value (nevermind, haha. It's been too long for me to edit.)

Comment: @Glen_b Ah! I was just typing to ask you what would be the purpose of taking the FT of a histogram. It looks like, for my purposes, (selecting out particular frequencies in voltage/time data), the histogram FFT is not useful.

Thank you both very much for the help, by the way.

Comment: But if you supply ROOT with a discrete-time set of voltages (which you could as easily pretend was a histogram), would it not return the FFT of that sequence, irrespective of what you want to use it for? When I used FFT for the purpose I mentioned, the FFT didn't know what values it was given, just that it was a sequence of numbers. Or does ROOT take raw data and *make* a histogram first? If that's the case, there are plenty of things that will do FFT for you without doing that.

Comment: user1715544 if your confusion is mostly resolved, could you indicate in which comments you think your question is answered? Someone should write an answer for this question.

Comment: @Glen_b It returns histograms of the FFT (real part, imaginary part, and such); it will FFT one dimensional histograms and two dimensional histograms. I think I'll need the two dimensional histogram in this case (that is, an FT of a time-voltage values).

The comment that most resolved my confusion was your comment with the line "The FFT of the bin counts is not really related to the FFT of the values from which the histogram was made," but in the whole correspondence helped me a lot. I will gladly vote your answer if you write one, which may only consist of your copying/pasting your comments.

Comment: Okay; I can't do so now though, I'll have to fix it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15345/discussion-between-amagicalfishy-and-glen-b).